# Выбор типа диаграммы

Tags: delphi

Где в компоненте Tchart выбрать тип диаграммы? Точно не знаю, но вроде как так можно. Пожалуйста, пошагово объясните.

Answer (score 1):

Из основных характеристик Chart, следует отметить:

> AllowPanning позволяет пользователю прокручивать видимую часть графика, манипулируя >
> правой кнопкой мыши.
>
> AllowZoom даёт возможность пользователю изменять масштаб изображения, вырезая фрагменты графика или диаграммы.
>
> Title отвечает за заголовок диаграммы.
>
> BottomAxis, LeftAxis, RightAxis отвечают за характеристики осей, актуально для графиков и некоторых видов диаграмм.
>
> LeftWall, BottomWall, BackWall отвечают за некоторые области трёхмерных отображений графиков.
>
> SeriesList отвечает за список некоторых серий, изображаемых в компоненте.
>
> View3d даёт возможность трёхмерного отображения диаграммы.
>
> View3DOptions отвечает за изменение характеристик трёхмерного изображения.
>
> Chart3DPercent задаёт масштаб трёхмерности.

[Взято отсюда](http://www.delphi-box.ru/view_post.php?id=73)

Answer (score 1):

Кликаем по компоненту дважды, и появится окно. Там есть разные типы диаграмм: трёхмерные и двумерные, круговые и столбчатые или графики. Тип следует выбирать, исходя из требуемой задачи, да и работа с каждым типом графика немного различается.

Выбираем тип графика (если на одном компоненте должно быть два графика и больше, выбираем ещё раз), затем на вкладке `Axis` можно настроить оси, на вкладке `Scale` (максимальные и минимальные значения для осей: `Top` - вертикальная ось, `Bottom` — горизонтальная), на `Title` — названия осей.

На закладке `Titles` можно указать название графика, на закладке `Walls` — настроить параметры стен (цвета и т. п.), на закладке `Panel` — настроить окантовку самого компонента и градиент, на вкладке `3D` — покрутить график как нужно.

Вот короткий пример по работе с графиком:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i: Integer;
begin
// Бросил 2 компонента Chart на форму
// Одному добавил 3 серии (Line), другому - одну (Pie)
  // Строю графики
  For i:=-10 To 10 Do
    Begin
     Series1.AddXY(i, i*i*i, '', clRed);
     Series2.AddXY(i, 10*Abs(i), '', clGreen);
     Series3.AddXY(i, Sqr(i), ''+IntToStr(Sqr(i)), clBlue);
    End;
  Series1.Title:='Куб';
  Series2.Title:='Модуль';
  Series3.Title:='Квадрат';

 // Круговая диаграмма
  Randomize;
  With Series4 Do
    Begin
      Clear;
      Add(Random(100), 'Delphi', clPurple);
      Add(Random(100), 'Java', clRed);
      Add(Random(100), 'C', clGreen);
      Add(Random(100), 'C++', clBlue);
      Add(Random(100), 'C#', clAqua);
    End;

end;
```